# Reading a text file

Tags: c

Hello I wrote this code for following question:
Write a C program that reads a text file into an array of character. You may assume that the file contains no more than 1000 characters. But code prints only first character of text. Where do I make mistake?

```
FILE *wse;
char a[1000];
int i;

    wse=fopen("21e.txt","r");

    for(i=0;i!=100;i++);
    {
    fscanf(wse,"%c",&a[i]);
    printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
```

Comment: why don't you try fgets directly since you have already allocated the supposed to be space for it, since fscanf stops at the first soace ?

Comment: Or just `fread` the whole file. There seems to be no reason to use any tokenising function.

Comment: your `for` loop has empty body. Please remove the semicolon after `for(i=0;i!=100;i++)`  - also `i < 100` would be safer…   (-:

Comment: @naber2 Kindly mark an answer and close the question which will be helpful to the forum and its members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step back a minute and learn the alternatives you have for input in C. You have *character oriented* input functions (`getchar()`, `fgetc()`, etc..) which will read a file one-character-at-a-time. You then have *line-oriented* input functions (e.g. `fgets` and `getline`) which will read lines of input at a time, and finally you have *block-oriented* input functions such as `fread` and `read` that you can use to read the entire file into a single block of memory. (there are some other tools for copying and memory access such as `sendfile` and `mmamp` that can also be utilized, but probably not intended here. The `scanf` family of functions, while they do have there uses, are not intended to read differing values over multiple lines.

Your basic approach should either be *character-oriented* input or *line-oriented* input to read a file into an array. The easier or the two would probably be *line-oriented* input where you would read an entire line and then *tokenize* the line into separate words with `strtok` (or by using a start and end pointer to walk down each line after it is read separating words).

Take a stab an your chosen approach and post back when you get stuck. We are happy to help.

A short example of using `fgets` to read each line following by `strtok` to separate each line into words could be something similar to the following. **note**: the program will read from the filename given on the command line (or from `stdin` by default if no name is given)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum {MAXC = 1000};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    char *delims = " \t\n.,:;";  /* word separators for strtok */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* always validate file is open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {  /* read each line into buf */
        char *p = buf;
        printf ("\n line:  %s\n tokens:\n", buf);
        /* tokenize buf into words with strtok */
        for (p = strtok (buf, delims); p; p = strtok (NULL, delims))
            printf ("   %s\n", p);
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);  /* close if not reading stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example/Output**

```
$ ./bin/strtok_fgets_file <dat/captnjack.txt

 line:  This is a tale

 tokens:
   This
   is
   a
   tale

 line:  Of Captain Jack Sparrow

 tokens:
   Of
   Captain
   Jack
   Sparrow

 line:  A Pirate So Brave

 tokens:
   A
   Pirate
   So
   Brave

 line:  On the Seven Seas.

 tokens:
   On
   the
   Seven
   Seas
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a *logical* error which makes it broken - very easy to fix.

- Your for loop has *empty body* - that's why it only prints the first character. *Semicolon* deleted.

There is also a style issue in checking the value of the counter:

- Although *checking* `i` against *not* being `100` won't make your code fail if everything else is OK, it's more common and conforming to your task specification to check its value for being *less than* `100`, or whichever constant you want.

Although this may not be the most elegant way of completing such a task, it's a rework of your read-by-character method code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
 FILE *wse;
 char a[1000];
 int i;

  if((wse=fopen("3.txt","r")) == NULL)//always check for file errors!
      return 1;

  for( i=0 ; i<100 ; i++ )
  {
      if(fscanf(wse,"%c",&a[i]) != 1) //check against end of file!
          break;
      printf("%c",a[i]);
  }
  fclose(wse);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux - your suggestion is very valuable - I improved my answer on it - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `fgetc` and `putchar`, since you are reading character-by character

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
```

Also, check the return value of `fopen`. It returns a `NULL` on failure.

Comment: Since the objective is to read the file into an array of `char`, the printing shown in the question is probably just diagnostic checking (a good idea).  This misses the problem with the code in the question, which was [pointed out correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105074/reading-a-text-file#comment61752805_37105074) by [user3078414](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078414/user3078414).

Answer (score 1):

Please find the corrected code :

```
FILE *wse;
char a[1000];
int i=0;

wse=fopen("21e.txt","r");

while(fscanf(wse,"%c",&a[i]) == 1)
{
    printf("%c",a[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Firstly, I corrected the code by removing your semicolon after the for loop. And secondly, replaced for with while loop so that it reads till end of file. It is because if the loop crosses EOF(End Of File), it might crash.